# list mysql data in 3 columns alphabetical vertical

Tags: php, mysql

I have this statement that works fine, but list alphabetical from left to right across 3 columns.  I want it to list alphabetical vertically down the column and then continue onto the next column.  Anyone know how I can do this.

```
$models = mysql_query("SELECT model, id FROM model where make='$phonemake' order by model asc") or die(mysql_error());      
$count = 0;    
$max = 3;    
while($model = mysql_fetch_array( $models ))
{    
    $count++;    
    echo "<div style='float:left; width:31%; padding-right:5px;'>".$model['model']."&nbsp;<a href='include/delete-model.php?id=".$model['id']."' onclick='return makesure".$model['id']."();'>Delete</a></div>";
    if($count >= $max){
        //reset counter
        $count = 0;
        //end and restart
        echo"<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

echo the data in a UL LIST , and use your counter to set the number of rows in the UL LIST , when counter is reaches max, create a new list and continue displaying. Personally i would use:

```
if($counter%3==0) {
   create new list
}
```

this way you dont need to reset the counter everytime.

Comment: thanks v-x i tried and got the same results before alphabetical across the columns.

Comment: Johny thanks for the reply and you explain in more detail.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

You can buffer result into array and change the order of adding of divs

The code could look like this:

```
$allmodels = array();
while($model = mysql_fetch_array( $models ))
{    
  $allmodels[] = $model;
}
for($i = 0; 3 * $i < count($allmodels); $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++)
    {
        if(isset($allmodels[($i * 3) + $j]))
        {
          $model = $allmodels[($i * 3) + $j];
          // print your stuff here...
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can somehow reorder items in the sql query, maybe dump that to the temporary table or play with mysql_data_seek.